# symfony2 form is not displaying

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.2

I am learning symfony2 and i have created one form in controller which is as bellow.
the controller file as DefaultController.php

```
namespace Banner\TestBundle\Controller;

use Banner\TestBundle\Entity\Contact;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Banner\TestBundle\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Components\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
public function newAction(Request $request)
{

 echo "The controller is called ";
 $task = new Task();
 $task->setTask("Write a blog Post ");
 $task->setDueDate(new DateTime('tomorrow'));

 $form =  $this->createFormBuilder($task)
            ->add('task','text  ')
            ->add('duedate','date')
            ->getForm();
    return $this->render('BannerTestBundle:default:zoo.html.twig',array('form'=>$form->createView()));

}
}
```

my routing file is as below.
routing.yml

```
task_new:
pattern:  /task/{request}
defaults: { _controller: BannerTestBundle:Default:new}
```

and the zoo.html.twig file is as bellow.

```
{% extends '::page.html.twig' %}
    {% block title %}The Zoo{% endblock %}

    {% block content %}

        <form action="{{ path('task_new') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
                {{ form_widget(form) }}
            <input type="submit">   
        </form> 

    {% endblock %}
```

as i am passing the "task/GET" in my url it will shows the 'Request does not exist. error 500'.

what i basically want to do is when i pass the url the zoo.html.twig will be called. i want to display the form in zoo.html.twig.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to pass `$request` to your action and you don't need to put it in your route. The request object is available in global context. So

```
task_new:
    pattern:  /task-new
    defaults: { _controller: BannerTestBundle:Default:new}
```

You can either leave it this way

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
```

or have

```
public function newAction()
```

and access request object like this

```
$request  = $this->getRequest();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your routing file is not properly indented so the yaml will not parse properly.  Try:

> ```
> task_new:
>     pattern:  /task/{request}
>     defaults: { _controller: BannerTestBundle:Default:new}
> ```

Also:

1. It is probably a bad idea to override request that way
2. You don't appear to be doing anything with request in your controller